# S3 - need to download particular images from aws and download them in zip

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cakephp-2.0

I need to download images from AWS bucket into a local directory and zip download them.

I have tried my code, but can't figure out how will I copy the images into my local directory.

here is my function :

```
     public function commomUpload($contentId,$prop_id)
 {
    $client = S3Client::factory(array(
                'key' => 'my key',
                'secret' => '----secret-----',
            ));
    $documentFolderName = 'cms_photos';
    $docbucket = "propertiesphotos/$prop_id/$documentFolderName";
            $data = $this->Photo->find('all',array('conditions'=>array('Photo.content_id'=>$contentId)));

    //pr($data);die;
    $split_point = '/';

    foreach($data as $row){
        $string = $row['Photo']['aws_link'];

        $result = array_map('strrev', explode($split_point, strrev($string)));
        $imageName = $result[0];
        $result = $client->getObject(array(
            'Bucket' => $docbucket,
            'Key'    => $imageName
        ));
        $uploads_dir = '/img/uploads/';
        if (!copy($result, $uploads_dir)) {
            echo "failed to copy $result...\n";
        }
        //move_uploaded_file($imageName, "$uploads_dir/$imageName");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont complicate things. There exists a very simple tools called s3cmd. Install it in any platforms.[Click here](http://s3tools.org/s3cmd) to know more. Once you download the images from the s3,use can either use gzip or zip it using just a bash script. Dont forget to configure your s3cmd. You need to have AWS access key and secret key with you.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Amazon S3 cakephp plugin https://github.com/fullybaked/CakeS3